# Rest API, save nested models in one request

Tags: rest, design-patterns

As I know in rest we need to save each model in separate request. What if I have 3-4 levels of nested models and would like to save it all in one request, whats the best practice? (Rails, PHP, Node.js)

Answer (score 1):

REST doesn't really talk about models, it talks about resources.

It's fine in REST services for 'some data' (your model) to be represented by multiple resources.

So if you define a new resource that combines all these models into a single larger model, then it would also be acceptable for you to submit a PUT request there and update everything in 1 request, atomically.

One thing to look out for though is caching. If you heavily rely on caching, updating the big resource does not automatically invalidate all the sub-resources in the cache. As far as I know, there's no standard way yet to tell a client that other resources should be expelled from the cache. There's a 2011 draft, but it seems abandoned:

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-nottingham-linked-cache-inv-04

Comment: Thx a lot, Im interesting in how to code this part of program where we combine and save data. What if nested models deleted, updated and etc?

Comment: @Costa if you're stuck on specific things, I would suggest you ask 1 or more specific new questions on stack overflow.